# How to remove hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1) I created an image with an opacity of 1. When you hover over it, the opacity becomes .3 and a button appears over the image. The problem, is that when you hover over the button, the opacity of the image returns to 1. How can I make the opacity of the image stay .3 when the hover is both over the image OR the button?

2) When you click play, the original image changes to a new image. But since the mouse is over the image, the new image has an opacity .3. How can I set the new image to have an opacity of 1 even when its hovered?

```js
var originalImgSrc = $('img').attr('src');

// Change image on button click
$(".the-buttons").click(function() {

  $('img').attr("src", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/blitzbase-assets/assets/2.gif");
  $(this).addClass("hide");
});

//Restore image on mouse out
$('.show-image img').mouseout(function() {
  $('img').attr("src", originalImgSrc);
  $('.the-buttons').removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
div.show-image {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #333;
}

div.show-image img {
  opacity: 1;
  background: white;
}

div.show-image img:hover {
  opacity: .3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

div.show-image:hover input {
  display: block;
}

div.show-image input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

div.show-image input.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png/09f/fff" />
  <input class="the-buttons" type="button" value="Play" />
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to add `transition` besides `-webkit-transition` for non-WebKit browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/9DS2r/14/)

Here's the answer to both of your questions.

1. Put the hover on the parent:

   `.show-image:hover img`
2. Add the "hide" class on the parent and change the opacity that way.

   $(this).parent().addClass("hide");

   div.show-image.hide img{
       opacity: 1;
   }
3. To add the play button back on hover after clicking the first time you would have to remove the hide class from the parent in your mouse out function:

   $('.the-buttons').parent().removeClass("hide");

Comment: Hey @MathiasaurusRex - thanks so much! This solved exactly my two problems. The only new problem that happens now is that after I click the button and the image gets replaced, I can't see the button again. How can I reset it so that it functions again like it did in the beginning state?

Comment: @ori sorry missed that part: You would have to add the parent selector in the mouseout event. http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/9DS2r/14/

$('.the-buttons').parent().removeClass("hide");

Answer (score 3):

change your css
from this:

```
div.show-image img:hover {
     opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

to this:

```
div.show-image:hover img {
     opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Hope this helps. Full snippet:

```js
var originalImgSrc = $('img').attr('src');

// Change image on button click
$(".the-buttons").click(function() {

  $('img').attr("src", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/blitzbase-assets/assets/2.gif");
  $(this).addClass("hide");
});

//Restore image on mouse out
$('.show-image img').mouseout(function() {
  $('img').attr("src", originalImgSrc);
  $('.the-buttons').removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
div.show-image {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #333;
}

div.show-image img {
  opacity: 1;
  background: white;
}

div.show-image:hover img {
  opacity: .3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

div.show-image:hover input {
  display: block;
}

div.show-image input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

div.show-image input.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png/09f/fff" />
  <input class="the-buttons" type="button" value="Play" />
</div>
```

Comment: And note that the jQuery to "restore" the image is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I removed your opacity from the CSS, and placed it within your jQuery function. I also replaced your event handler with .hover(), and targeted the parent container.

```
$('.show-image').hover(
  function() {
    $(this)
      .find('img').css('opacity', '.3').end()
      .find('input').show();
  }, function() {
    $(this)
      .find('img').css('opacity', '1').attr("src", originalImgSrc).end()
      .find('input').hide();
  }
);
```

---

```js
var originalImgSrc = $('img').attr('src');

// Change image on button click
$(".the-buttons").click(function() {

  $('img').attr("src", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/blitzbase-assets/assets/2.gif").css('opacity', 1);
  $(this).hide();
});

$('.show-image').hover(
  function() {
    $(this)
      .find('img').css('opacity', '.3').end()
      .find('input').show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this)
      .find('img').css('opacity', '1').attr("src", originalImgSrc).end()
      .find('input').hide();
  }
);
```

```css
div.show-image {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #333;
}

div.show-image img {
  background: white;
}

div.show-image:hover input {
  display: block;
}

div.show-image input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png/09f/fff" />
  <input class="the-buttons" type="button" value="Play" />
</div>
```

---

Also, note the update I made to restore opacity on clicking 'Play'.

Comment: That looks good, but why does the button not come back with the next hover of the second image?

Comment: I wasn't aware that it needed to. All you need to do is remove the 'hide' class on hover, in that case.

Comment: Thanks Dean.DePue.. Yes @Steve - I need the button to come back but only with the first image... not the second image.

Comment: After reviewing your question again, I made some further edits to the code. Please check out the updated link in my answer.

Comment: @ori be careful with these solutions that change your css via javascript. Javascript should create functionality and leave your styles alone. You don't want to look at your stylesheet years from now and wonder why the styles aren't the same.

Comment: That being said, this could easily be modified to add and remove classes that utilize the stylesheet. Either way would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseover`/`mouseout` events to add/remove class and add css to that class, I added the `.hovered` class.

```js
var originalImgSrc = $('img').attr('src');

// Change image on button click
$(".the-buttons").click(function() {

  $('img').attr("src", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/blitzbase-assets/assets/2.gif");
  $(this).addClass("hide");
});

function addHOVER() {
  $('.show-image img').addClass("hovered");
}

function remHOVER() {
  $('.show-image img').removeClass("hovered");
}

$(".show-image img").mouseover(addHOVER);
$(".show-image .the-buttons").mouseover(addHOVER);
$(".show-image .the-buttons").mouseout(remHOVER);
//Restore image on mouse out
$('.show-image img').mouseout(function() {
  $('img').attr("src", originalImgSrc);
  remHOVER();
  $('.the-buttons').removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
div.show-image {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #333;
}

div.show-image img {
  opacity: 1;
  background: white;
}

div.show-image img.hovered {
  opacity: .3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

div.show-image:hover input {
  display: block;
}

div.show-image input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

div.show-image input.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png/09f/fff" />
  <input class="the-buttons" type="button" value="Play" />
</div>
```